# Bind IONIC to differents databases

Tags: android, database, ionic-framework

I need to develop an application (IONIC-Android) that can potentially link different databases, but only one at a time. The application will have different clients, who use different database engines. Therefore, it would have a configuration file that establishes the connection parameters when starting the application. The app only needs to make 'select' type queries.
IONIC offers some solution in this regard? You could guide my investigation a little?

Thanks for read.

Answer (score 0):

Check the official [Ionic Storage](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage) documentation and specifically the section related to configuring Local Forage

Comment: Thanks. I've given a look at the subject and I think it's a good solution, but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to link with multiple databases with a high level abstraction. Something ORM style. It would be a utility similar to Ionic Storage, but with extensible compatibility to other SQL engines, such as ORACLE, SQL Server, PostGree, etc. I need to be able to incorporate compatibility with other engines later without significant changes in the application. The intention was to know if someone had worked with something like that from IONIC.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this:

http://typeorm.io/#/

I will analyze it and then share the conclusions.